# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -8

Tags: hibernate, mappingexception

I am getting below error while using `createSqlQuery(query);` method of **hibernate**.

```
error: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -8
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a data type for the attribute which you are using to retrieve the values in the query.

Example: `Native Sql Query: select NAME from EMP;`

Java Code:

```
SQLQuery query = Session.createSQLQuery(NativeSQLQuery).addScalar("NAME",Hibernate.String);
```

the above code will solve the dialect issue.